# How do I get a yum_package resource to run before a chef_gem package?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am writing a recipe that uses ruby_libvirt, it requires libvirt-devel.

So I need yum_package libvirt-devel to run before chef_gem ruby_libvirt.

I put the yum_package in a recipe a head of the chef_gem, in the role runlist.
I was hoping that would force the issue.

chef_gem seems to be evaluated ahead of time.

Answer (score 7):

As `chef_gem` installs ruby gems in *compile* stage, you should make `yum_package` to run in this stage too.

```
yum_package 'libvirt-devel' do
  action :nothing
end.run_action :install

chef_gem 'ruby_libvirt'
```

`chef_gem` resource however should be used only in cases when Chef requires some gem to be installed (e.g. when it uses it further in recipe). If you just need to install a gem use `gem_package` resource. It is evaluated in *execution* phase like any other resource.

```
yum_package 'libvirt-devel'
gem_package 'ruby_libvirt'
```

[More on *compile* and *execution* phases of Chef-run](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html).

Comment: Perfect. I'll give it a try.  Yes, I need gem_package for that reason. Want to use the library from a recipe.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried putting it under a ruby block?

```
yum_package "libvirt-devel"

ruby_block 'chef_gem_gemname' do
  block do
    chef_gem "gemname"
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Chef gem is designed to be run at compile-time. It should not be used in a Ruby block.

Comment: @sethvargo this isn't true you just can't call it with `chef_gem` you have to call it like `Chef::Provider::ChefGem` that.

Comment: @abc123 chef_gem _definitely_ runs at compile time - that's the primary difference between chef_gem and gem_package: https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html